# Excel Pivot table Aggregation

Tags: excel, pivot-table

So I have this small data set:

[Pivot table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wIDfB.png)

A has 9 total players and total cost is 32 so average cost of a player on team A should 32/9=3.55. But the the pivot table says its 3 which obviously wrong. How do I get the right answer on the pivot table.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a math problem. You are taking the Average of "Average Cost" and the average of averages is not usually the "average" you are looking for. I would say try taking the sums of ALL of each team's players and costs prior to averaging.

Restructuring your base data will be the easiest way to get your PivotTable to display the average you are hoping for.

Comment: That was just me experimenting with all the value options. I guess I was just wondering if there was smart excel option that would group the fields together and give an accurate answer from a list of values,

Comment: @RishavDry this isnt an excel problem. There isnt a pivot option that will parse portions of of an existing average to then re-average the portions